# Copying a single database from DB2 10.5 to DB2 11.5

Tags: restore, db2, db2-luw, db2-10.5, db2-11.5

What is the easiest way to **copy a single database** (has no large objects) from **DB2 10.5 Express-C** instance to **DB2 11.5 Community Edition** instance?

I tried [this method](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/214223/225182) but obviously `db2 restore database` is meant to be used only with the originating instance because the original database path is referenced in the error message: `SQL1051N  The path "/var/lib/db/db2/db2inst1" does not exist or is not valid.`

Comment: You need a [redirected restore](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=restore-performing-redirected-operation).

Comment: Thanks. Adding the switch `redirect` did the job. However, I'm testing with a small sample db and restoring seems to take a long time. `db2 list utilities show detail` have been showing `State = Executing` now for more than an hour.